# Extrating values from object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

`{dogs:214,cats:211,mouses:213,horses:203,beatles: 42}`

So I have an object shaped like this object above. I need to extract the so called "key" from here (dogs,cats,mouses....) and put them in the dropdown menu like options to pick(but leaving their values as they are ). Anyone have an idea?

Comment: `Object.keys()`

Comment: yes , thank you for your feedback. Im sorry for not posting more infos (code etc.) but this will do. Ty once more

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys() might be helpful